# Create a type from existing types which only contains functions (and nested functions)

Tags: typescript

Not sure if this is possible. I can extract *only* functions from a type already like this:

```
interface Foo {
    doSomethingFoo(): void
    bar: Bar
    anotherProperty: boolean
    arrayProperty: bar[],
    arrayPrimitive: string[],
}

interface Bar {
    doSomethingBar(): void
    anotherProperty: string
}

type PickFunctions<T> = { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends Function ? P : never]: T[P] } 

type fooFunctions = PickFunctions<Foo> 
/*
type fooFunctions = {
    doSomethingFoo: () => void;
}
*/
```

What I'm looking for is, given type `Foo`, I'd like to get an object which contains all functions of foo, and all objects inside foo with only their functions. If the objects are arrays, I want to "Unarray" the object into a instance of that single type, since all I care about is functions, not data across various instances of objects.

```
declare type OnlyFunctions<T>

type fooAndNestedFunctions = OnlyFunctions<Foo>
/*
Should be:
type fooAndNestedFunctions = {
    doSomethingFoo: () => void;
    bar: {
        doSomethingBar: () => void;
    };
    arrayProperty: {
        doSomethingBar: () => void;
    };
}
```

After the proposal from @jcalz I was able to come up with what I believe is a solution so the problem:

```
type RecursivePickFunctions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends any[] ? Unarray<T[K]> extends object ? K : never : T[K] extends object ? K : never
  ]: T[K] extends Function ? T[K] :
  T[K] extends object[] ? RecursivePickFunctions<Unarray<T[K]>> : RecursivePickFunctions<T[K]>
}

type Unarray<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : T

type fooFunctions = RecursivePickFunctions<Foo>
/* type FooFunctions = {
    doSomethingFoo: () => void;
    bar: RecursivePickFunctions<Bar>;
    arrayProperty: RecursivePickFunctions<Bar>;
} */
```

Comment: These sorts of deeply nested types tend to have bizarre edge cases that need significant refactorings to resolve.  Please check if [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mA2q1W) meets your needs, by testing any use cases you care about that might not be covered by your example. If it works for them, I'll write up an answer explaining it.  If it fails somewhere, please [edit] to add the use case to your question description.

Comment: Hi @jcalz Thanks for this. Your proposal did in fact make me realize that they were some unhandled cases that I didn't think about.

In particular, I need to do the same thing with arrays of objects. That is to say, given an array of objects that contain functions, I needed a n output type of a single object's functions. (Hard to put these concepts into words).

Going off what you suggested, I proposed a solution in my main post. If you have time to take a look at it, assuming my goal makes sense, I'd appreciate feedback.

Comment: Self-answers are encouraged but they belong as answers, not as edits to the question.

Comment: I will go ahead and move it to an answer then. Thanks!